# Performing Conditional Logistic Regression in R

Tags: r, multiple-regression, matching

Using the `MatchIt` library, specifically coarsened exact matching, I have created two groups matched on variable `E`. The code I did to do this looks like:

```
library(MatchIt)
library(dplyr)

e.match <- matchit(E ~ X1 + X2 + X3, data=x.data, method="cem")
e.data <- match.data(e.match)
e.data0 <- filter(e.data, E=="0")
e.data1 <- filter(e.data, E=="1")
```

The variable `x.data` has outcome variables `Y1`, `Y2`, and `Y3`. Now I would like to perform conditional logistic regression comparing `e.data0` (or `E == 0`) to `e.data1` (or `E == 1`) for the binary categorical outcome `Y1`.

Using `clogit` from the `survival` library, would the following code be correct?

```
library(survival)
clr <- clogit(Y1 ~ E, data=e.data)
```

I am not using the `strata` keyword and seem to get results, however every example that I have seen googling for the answer shows the use of the `strata` keyword, which is why I am confused. Thank you.

Comment: You might be better asking this on R-help

Comment: Please `dput()` the data necessary for a reproducible example

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should use the `strata` keyword:

```r
clr <- clogit(Y1 ~ strata(E), data=e.data)
```